# Is there anyway to auto scale-out based on schedule not policy for dataproc in GCP (google cloud platform)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

It's straight forward.
The system i am developing will be provisioned in dataproc (google cloud platform)
And due to some business feature about our system, we can figure expected data processed in the future.
So, i just want to do scale-out dataproc based on it.

Is there any idea to scale-out dataproc by scheduler or API implemented by our side ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the size of a Dataproc cluster using a `gcloud dataproc clusters update` or an equivalent API call in one of the Dataproc client libraries, see the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/update). It also supports [setting an auto scaling policy](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/autoscaling), where the cluster can grow and shrink based on the load on the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You should use combination of Cloud scheduler and [manual scale out](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/scaling-clusters#gcloud) method for this situation.

Create Cloud scheduler job runs manual scale out API call like below.

You must know about [cron syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to use cron scheduling for your scailing job.

[image]

In this scenario, You can only specify number of nodes your cluster uses, not number of incremental. This is a limitation of this solution. Below is example of API call.

```
PATCH /v1/projects/project-id/regions/us-central1/clusters/example-cluster?updateMask=config.worker_config.num_instances,config.secondary_worker_config.num_instances
{
  "config": {
  "workerConfig": {
  "numInstances": 4
},
"secondaryWorkerConfig": {
  "numInstances": 2
}
  },
  "labels": null
}
```

For a detailed description of Dataproc API, See [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.clusters/patch).

Comment: Good answer, but if the questioner wants to overcome the limitation of Cloud Scheduler, he/she can consider Cloud Composer which is more flexible.